# Avoiding individual database calls for count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter-cache

My models look like this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :year, :rotten_id, :audience_score,
    :critics_score, :runtime, :synopsis, :link, :image

  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :actors, :through => :jobs
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :movies, :through => :jobs
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :movie_id, :actor_id

  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :actor
end
```

When I'm displaying my index of Actors, I'd like to show the number of movies *each actor* has starred in. I can do this with `@actor.movies.count`, however this generates an SQL query for `each actor`. With, say, 30 actors, this will result in 30 extra queries in addition to the initial.

Is there any way to include the count of movies each actor has participated in, in the initial `Actor.all` call? And thereby getting things done with only one call. Extra bonus if this was sorted by said count.

**Update:**
All answers provided has been helpful, and though it turned into some dirt-slinging-contest at some point, it worked out well. I did a mish-mash of all your suggestions. I added a movies_counter column to my Actor model. In my Job model I added `belongs_to :actor, :counter_cache => :movies_counter`. This works brilliantly, and is automatically updated when i create or destroy a movie, without me adding any further code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sam noticed, you should add new column to `actors` table `movies_counter`

```
rails g migration add_movies_counter_to_actor movies_counter:integer
```

Now you can edit your migration

```
class AddMoviesCounterToActor < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :actors, :movies_counter, :integer, :default => 0

    Actor.reset_column_information
    Actor.all.each do |a|
      a.update_attribute :movies_counter, a.movies.count
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :actors, :movies_counter
  end
end
```

And run it

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then you should add two callbacks: `after_save` and `after_destroy`

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :year, :rotten_id, :audience_score,
    :critics_score, :runtime, :synopsis, :link, :image

  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :actors, :through => :jobs

  after_save :update_movie_counter
  after_destroy :update_movie_counter

  private
  def update_movie_counter
    self.actors.each do |actor|
      actor.update_attribute(:movie_count, actor.movies.count)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call `some_actor.movies_counter`

Comment: you're reimplementing the counter_cache feature.

Comment: Here is has_many :through association, which haven't got counter_cache option

Comment: You're right, this looks like the best solution although you should probably be using `Actor.increment_counter` instead of doing a full count each time.

Comment: @Adam, it can be increment or decrement (when deletes). So we can write two methods for each callback with `increment_counter` and `decrement_counter` or we can use this solution, which has got one more sql request, but it is not importaint if project is not kind of highload

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your Actor table called 'movie_count'. Then add a call back in your Actor model that updates that column.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actors, :through => :jobs
  before_save :update_movie_count
  def update_movie_count
     self.actor.update_attribute(:movie_count, self.movies.size)
  end
end
```

That way your just have an integer that gets updated instead of calling all records.

Comment: I would do the update_movie_count in my Job model though, right? As a movie has several actors, and it's not really until a Job is created that the count should increase.

But yeah, I get the idea. It's a simple work around when you're aware of utilities as before_save. Thanks

Comment: @sam you're reimplementing the counter_cache feature.

Comment: @sam actually it doesn't quite work here, so you'd have to reimplement it.

Comment: @Adam Lassek. and besides as @flOOr pointed out your answer that you deleted was wrong because this is a has_many through so I'm not reimplementing the counter_cache.

Comment: :counter_cache doesnt work, as stated... but will some implementation of :counter_sql work?